# I have remapped super+L but it still locks my screen instead of doing what I want

Tags: shortcut-keys

I have reassigned my workspace switching keys to Super+h, Super+j, Super+k, and Super+l because the arrow keys are too cumbersome. They work perfectly except for Super+l which instead just locks my screen. This key combanation is very convenient for me as I don't need to move either hand from the homerow keys to switch between workspaces.

I'm using 14.04 (64bit). I reassigned my keys using 'All Settings -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts -> Navigation -> Switch to workspace X'.

Answer (score 1):

You probably just need to unset the lock screen shortcut first:

[image]

Just click on the right side of the shortcut, and when it says 'New Accelerator', press <kbd>Backspace</kbd> to unset it

Comment: The lock screen shortcut (in All Settings -> Keyboard -> Shortcut -> System -> Lock Screen) has Ctrl + Alt + L as the key combo. Removing it does nothing for Super + L. I've looked through all the shortcut menus and can't find a different Lock Screen option or anything using Super + L.

Comment: Are you using Unity? - it has the (not so) nice feature of hard-coding things in for their 'design view' or something, which may be the issue... does setting 'Super'+'L' as the shortcut for anything else work?

Comment: I am using Unity and nothing works with Super + L. It locks the screen no matter what I assign Super + L to. Is there a way to change the Unity hard codings?